# How to recreate Android 4.0 Lockscreen

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I was wondering if it was possible to recreate the android 4.0 lockscreen within an application. I want to use it as the way to navigate through my app. Is it possible to pull the source of the lockscreen from a ROM and then modify it to fit? Does anyone know how it would be recreated? It doesn't seem like anyone's tried this before according to google or the similar questions on the side, any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141426/423170), the source code for the Android lock screen can be found in the `platform/frameworks/policies/base` Git repository, in the `phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java` file. You can read the instructions on how to [download the Android source code here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), or you can read the source file online [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_policies_base/blob/master/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java).

**EDIT:** I am sorry, I probably posted the source code for an older version of the lock screen than the one you were looking for (from sometime around 2010, I believe). Nevertheless, the Android lock screen from Ice Cream Sandwhich should probably be in the Android source code somewhere, so you should be able to just search a bit and hopefully find it.

Comment: The answer you linked was updated and has both old and new lockscreen source code